# Previous page wordpress function

Tags: wordpress, function, request-uri

I need to write a function in WordPress.

I would like to function to work on this principle:
- Checking function if the user is logged,
- Checking whether I am currently on the "my-account"
- And what i need (Previous page is the "checkout" subpage)

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'my-account' ) ) {
        wp_redirect('http://google.com');
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

I need to add a function wp_get_referer?

Comment: what actually want to do??

Comment: Add another variable, that is, if the previous address of the page is / checkout / and add this to is_page and is_usser_logged

Comment: As I understand if user is logout and click back it redirect to home page??

Comment: No :) The link sending the information, why do I need this guide :)
[link]vinecase.de/instr.png[/link]

Comment: Pacyk can't understand flow.How can we achieve this do you have idea??

Comment: Listen :)
I have two forms, login and registration on two different sub-pages that use a single file.

I want to after a successful login / register correctly from the "My-account" transported me to the sub -> my-account. At the moment everything is okay.

The problem is with the other side - checkout.

I want to on this page, after a successful login / register correct, moved me to the page -> http: // x. (Other subpage) Not so, as in the case of login and registration by sub "my-account".

Now do you understand?

Comment: after check out you have to move to account page? check if user is login.

Comment: You can use : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: No you do not have enough function is_user_logged. The problem is that somehow I have to distinguish the page "my-account" from the "checkout". Because after a successful login / successful login, I would like to redirect the page not to "my-account" (as in the case of logging from the my-account), only to subpage "x". Two diffrent redirections, first on subpage "my-account" to "a", second by subpage "checkout" to "b"

https://vinecase.de/guide2.png

Comment: Thank you. Do you know yet how to add the variable that I gave in the first post?

Comment: you can use session for that

Comment: I know nothing about that at all, can you help me with this code?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to hook to late, the headers are already sent.

You can use other action like `init` or `wp_loaded`

```
 add_action('init', 'add_login_check');
```

The [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) page shows the order of the WordPress actions.

Hope it helps !